# Your Android SDK is missing , out of date,or is missing templates

Tags: android, ubuntu, sdk

I just installed android Studio on my computer (Ubuntu) and I'm getting this problem every time I try to create a new project, problem this that does not allow me to actually start an android studio project. I have seen some solutions on internet which says I should go to Configure->Project Defaults->Project Structure and make some changes there, in the SDKs field, what happens is that the only opition that shows up to me in projecture structure is the field SDK location, I Don't know what else I could do, so I'd like to know if someone can help me, thank you.

Comment: did u update your sdk?

Comment: In older versions of Android Studio, as in last week and before, the SDK was included in the Android Studio folder. In the latest versions, the SDK is separate. Put it in your home folder, make sure there isn't an sdk folder in your android studio folder and try again, pointing the reference to your home folder SDK when it asks for it. Make sure you have the latest version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just had the same problem as you. The guys at Google are terrible at providing up-to-date documentation. First of all, Android Studio v0.8.14 does NOT come with SDK, even though on the website it says it does. You have to download the stand-alone SDK tools separately from this [link](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html). Then just unzip the file to some directory, like ~/Development. Open Android Studio, Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure. There provide the path to SDK (~/Development). It should find SDK and work finally.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Can someone please mark this answer as correct? It took me months to get this thing working. It's such a pain...

Comment: The current direct link is (2018--12-31):  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip  but, as others have already said in other responses to similar questions on SO, the best way is to let Android Studio handle the installation, because it will install other useful apps, too (emulator, platform tools, etc). In my case, I wasn't connected to the internet when I first started Android Studio, so I got stuck at the same error. After removing the ~/.AndroidStudio3.2 folder and a ./studio.sh restart, it asked me to download the necessary apps (note: the dowload had ~1GB!)

Answer (score -2):

Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates. You can configure your SDK by following:
`Configure | Project Defaults | Project Structure | SDKs`